# Wordpress LayerSlider JQuery Issues

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress site with a layerslider plugin,..I'm getting some jQuery issues, though i'm using "Wordpress 4.0" and "LayerSlider_v5.2.0" version, i'm not able to edit or create slider. This issue is in the "Layerslider Admin Panel". I tried JQuery Updater Plugin as suggested by the issue and even downloaded the latest version of JQuery Library i.e "jquery-2.1.1.min" and replaced it with the default one which is located in "wordpress-4.0\wordpress\wp-includes\js\jquery" in wordpress but still the issue is not getting resolved..

Plz help..

Screen Shot of the issues is added below..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the version check is just inaccurate. You're using 1.11.0, which is obviously higher than 1.7.2. Either the script which checks the version is just wrong, or the plugin doesn't actually support WordPress 4.0 / jQuery 1.11.0. From the [Compatibility notes](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246#item-description__compatibility):

> Requires jQuery 1.7 (working with 1.10.x or 2.x versions, please note
>   that jQuery 2.x is no more compatible with IE7 and 8!) & Greensock
>   Animation Engine
>
> Requires WordPress 3.5, compatible with WordPress 3.8+

This plugin is on the 5.3.2 version, which no longer appears to have the issue you're describing.

Looks like you'll either need to downgrade jQuery (not advised), or upgrade the plugin.

Comment: @mevius, so plz suggest me which Jquery version should i use..??

Comment: Default, WordPress 4.0, jQuery 1.11.0. You need to update the plugin. A fix has been applied to the plugin. If you look at the comments, you're not the only one that has had this issue: http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246/comments?filter=all&site=codecanyon.net&term=1.11.0&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @mevius Thank You for your valuable suggestion..:)